# Get constituent dataframes from one with multiple values in a column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a sample data frame below which has two values (Bus and Car+Minibus) in the `mode column` I have two questions, the first is how can I break this up into two data frames with single values as seen below. The second question is since I have a list of data frames with some occurring in the `input` format, how can I write a condition statement them.

input

```
                            Dest           a      b      c
Orig    Variable    Time    Mode            
  1        x          y     Bus           5.00  17.32   12.61
                            Car+Minibus   0.87  15.34   12.01
  2        x          y     Bus           5.00  14.72   10.15
                            Car+Minibus   10.47 3.03    11.05
  3        x          y     Bus           14.72 5.00    15.98
                            Car+Minibus   11.64 11.25   2.08
  4        x          y     Bus           15.15 14.62   5.94
                            Car+Minibus   12.02 9.25    5.80
```

outputs:

```
                            Dest           a      b      c
Orig    Variable    Time    Mode            
  1        x          y     Bus           5.00  17.32   12.61
  2        x          y     Bus           5.00  14.72   10.15
  3        x          y     Bus           14.72 5.00    15.98
  4        x          y     Bus           15.15 14.62   5.94


                            Dest           a      b      c
Orig    Variable    Time    Mode            
  1        x          y     Car+Minibus   0.87  15.34   12.01
  2        x          y     Car+Minibus   10.47 3.03    11.05
  3        x          y     Car+Minibus   11.64 11.25   2.08
  4        x          y     Car+Minibus   12.02 9.25    5.80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need check fourth level of `MultiIndex` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values(3) == 'Bus'

df1 = df[mask]

df2 = df[~mask]
```

But if want working with list of `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = [df11,df12,df13]

for df in dfs:
    mask = df.index.get_level_values(3) == 'Bus'
    df1 = df[mask]
    print (df1)
    df2 = df[~mask]
    print (df2)
```

Comment: assuming df3 is in the correct format, the loop will not operate on it right?

Comment: Maybe my `DataFrame`s in list was wrong called, so I change it. Then it should working nice, only is necessary same format of all dataframes in list.